# Does Oracle's "date'[yyyy-mm-dd]'" literal always use the yyyy-mm-dd pattern?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, plsql, oracle10g

Rephrased, given I use date like so:

```
date'2010-04-10'
```

, could the outcome be anything but April 10th 2010 (e.g. October 4th 2010)?

UPDATE I hear what you, and the docs, say. But...

When a batch job runs, with hard-coded date'yyyy-mm-dd':s, it fails for some (non-deterministic) calculations. Running the failing SQL statements in PL/SQL Developer *never* yields the same, incorrect, value.

First, I ran the same calculations (hundreds of thousands) with the date'' date literals replaced with the to_date('', '') function, and everything worked just fine.

Then, I used NHibernate and its LINQ provider, and replaced the hand-crafted SQL altogether. ... and everything worked just fine... NHibernate produces a '' date literal, with the time part included, BTW.

UPDATE A colleague of mine wrote some code, that can reproduce the error in our environment. He posted his findings (including the code) at Oracle Forums: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2304569&tstart=0

UPDATE Changed the title according to zerkms' answer.

Answer (score 16):

It is not *function*, but *date literal*. And, Yes, it always matches `YYYY-MM-DD` regardless any oracle settings.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a [link to Oracle 10g SQL reference, on datetime literals](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref364). Excerpt:

> The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and must be specified
>   in exactly this format `('YYYY-MM-DD')`. Alternatively you can specify
>   an Oracle date value, as in the following example:
>
> `TO_DATE('98-DEC-25 17:30','YY-MON-DD HH24:MI')`